# "Pseudo" subproject without code and just dependencies fails when signing is required because of the missing jar

Tags: gradle

I'd like to create a subproject that acts as sole anchor for dependencies, ie. it includes no source code. Users can simply depend on the artifact created by the subproject in order to get all the required dependencies. So i've created foo-bar/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":foo-barz")
    compile project(":foo-batz")
}
jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

That seems to work as expected, until signing comes into the build process. I've then get an error message

> :foo-bar:signArchives FAILED
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':foo-bar:signArchives' >
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/flo/code/foo/foo-bar/build/libs/foo-bar-4.0.1.jar (No such file
>   or directory)

How can I tell the signing plugin that it needs to sign just the pom file for this subproject?

Comment: Perhaps try to find a solution that doesn't apply the `java` plugin to that subproject. Not sure if there is a way though (to solve the problem in this way).

Comment: I currently configure the java plugin for every subproject with `subprojects { apply plugin: 'java' … }` Is there a way to exclude certain projects from this config? Something like `(subprojects - project(":foo-bar")) { apply plugin: 'java' … }`?

Comment: You can use `configure(subprojects - project(":foo-bar")) { ... }`.

Comment: Or `subprojects { if (<your project check here>) { <do stuff here> } }`

Comment: Please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: With a Maven project, you would set the packaging option. Is there a Gradle way to set that for the Maven output?

Comment: Actually it was a triple-post, he also asked in #gradle on FreeNode. *g*

Answer (score 1):

I'd say either do not apply the `java` plugin, then you also don't need to disable the `jar` task, or also disable the `signArchives` task like you disabled the `jar` task.

Comment: Disabling signArchives appears to be no options, since I want the resulting `.pom` to be signed. But disabling the java plugin seems to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with just creating an empty file with

`foo-bar/src/main/java/org/foo/bar/FooBarDummy.java`

so that all tasks are happy and an empty jar is created, signed and deployed. Thaks to Peter Niederwieser, Vampire and Daryl Teo for their input. I've found no elegant an easy solution to avoid that Dummy.java workaround.

<sup>This question was based on implementing [smack-java7](https://github.com/Flowdalic/Smack/tree/master/smack-java7)</sup>

Comment: There is no need to add a Java file in order to produce an empty Jar.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I'm sorry, but after `git clean -x -d -f` i get now: `Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/data/flo/code/smack/smack-java7/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'.
> A Jar can only accept a valid file or directory: /data/flo/code/smack/smack-java7/build/classes/main
`

Comment: Never seen this before. Maybe something particular to your build or to the `signing` plugin.